# Border around list box items(Silver Light)

Tags: silverlight

I am adding items to Listbox on run time.

Each ListBoxItem is a child View. Each time when i add a item, a new listboxitem will be added to the parent paga.

My child view has a Border. when i dynamically add a one more child view, I can make out a gap between the two list box items.

could any one please help me out doing this without gap.

Answer (score 0):

The Padding on the ListBoxItem is the source of the spacing.  Here is one way you can set it to 0:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListBox>
```